# stick image in center, bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image in the center, but if I make the screen smaller the image goes to the righ.What not has to be. The image has to be responsive. So how to manage that the image will stay wiht the scaling?

I have this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12">
        <a class="logo" href="{channel.link(channel.browsestartpage())}">
            <img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/Logo_Franciscus_Gasthuis_Vlietland_PAYOFF_rgb.png')}" alt="logo Frasicus gasthuis &amp; Vlietland" class="img-responsive img-right" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5  col-xs-12" >
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="{html.location(cms.getdescendantbytitle(channel.browsestartpage(),'Beheer/Meta/Zoeken',Off), Autonomous)}" method="post">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q"  title="Type hier uw zoekterm"  placeholder="Ik zoek ..." />
                <input type="hidden" value="0" name="searchconcept" id="c"  />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" value="{locale.getstring('search',default='Zoek')}" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
                </span>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,
.h1,.h2,.h3,.h4,.h5,.h6,.h7,.h8 {
    font-weight:700;
}
h1,.h1 {
    font-size:1.8em;
}
h2,.h2 {
    font-size:1.6em;
}
h3,.h3 {
    font-size:1.4em;
}
h4,.h4,h5,.h5,h6,.h6 {
    font-size:1em;
}

.img-responsive.img-left {
    margin-right: auto; 
}
.img-responsive.img-center {
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
}
.img-responsive.img-right {
    margin-left: auto; 
}

.right {
    float:right;
}
.left {
    float:left;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.flex-row {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin:0;
}
.stretch {
    align-self:stretch;
}
```

Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 text-right">
        <a class="logo" href="{channel.link(channel.browsestartpage())}">
            <img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/Logo_Franciscus_Gasthuis_Vlietland_PAYOFF_rgb.png')}" alt="logo Frasicus gasthuis &amp; Vlietland" class="img-responsive img-center" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5  col-xs-12" >
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="{html.location(cms.getdescendantbytitle(channel.browsestartpage(),'Beheer/Meta/Zoeken',Off), Autonomous)}" method="post">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q"  title="Type hier uw zoekterm"  placeholder="Ik zoek ..." />
                <input type="hidden" value="0" name="searchconcept" id="c"  />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" value="{locale.getstring('search',default='Zoek')}" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
                </span>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,
.h1,.h2,.h3,.h4,.h5,.h6,.h7,.h8 {
    font-weight:700;
}
h1,.h1 {
    font-size:1.8em;
}
h2,.h2 {
    font-size:1.6em;
}
h3,.h3 {
    font-size:1.4em;
}
h4,.h4,h5,.h5,h6,.h6 {
    font-size:1em;
}

.img-responsive.img-left {
    margin-right: auto; 
}
.img-responsive.img-center {
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
}
.img-responsive.img-right {
    margin-left: auto; 
}

.right {
    float:right;
}
.left {
    float:left;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

a.logo { display: inline-block;}

.flex-row {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin:0;
}
.stretch {
    align-self:stretch;
}
```

Comment: Use `text-center` along with your  `class="col-md-7 col-xs-12"` and write *CSS* as: `a.logo { display: inline-block;}`.

Comment: Remove the image class ``img-right`` and add ``img-center``. And it makes it centered in it's column.

Comment: I updated the post. But still at some moment the logo goes to the right

Comment: @Vann'TileIanito ,he needs to give `display:block` as well to .img-center

Comment: @SavantTheIncredible can u create a fiddle, with dummy data ?

Comment: @SavantTheIncredible But it works ok now...

Comment: @Deepak [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fj171uq/)

Comment: @Vann'TileIanito thanx ! I just checked, `.img-responsive` already has a `display:block` property given

Comment: Oke, thank you!! all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the image using Bootstrap, you need to use the `center-block` class on the image, and then get rid of `inline-block` on the `a` class.

The fiddle also removes the `.img-responsive` classes...

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timgavin/tssgLxa3/)

Bootstrap pretty much has most of what you want built-in, so you don't have to create bunch of your own classes to align images and text :)

Edit: I'm not exactly sure of what you're trying to accomplish with your layout - so I left everything else as-is - but you could probably clean up your HTML and CSS even further and use more of Bootstrap's classes to achieve what you want.

```
<style>
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,
.h1,.h2,.h3,.h4,.h5,.h6,.h7,.h8 {
    font-weight:700;
}
h1,.h1 {
    font-size:1.8em;
}
h2,.h2 {
    font-size:1.6em;
}
h3,.h3 {
    font-size:1.4em;
}
h4,.h4,h5,.h5,h6,.h6 {
    font-size:1em;
}

.right {
    float:right;
}
.left {
    float:left;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.flex-row {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin:0;
}
.stretch {
    align-self:stretch;
}
</style>



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 text-right">
        <a class="logo" href="{channel.link(channel.browsestartpage())}">
            <img src="{channel.link('/designs/SFVG/Logo_Franciscus_Gasthuis_Vlietland_PAYOFF_rgb.png')}" alt="logo Frasicus gasthuis &amp; Vlietland" class="img-responsive center-block" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5  col-xs-12" >
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="{html.location(cms.getdescendantbytitle(channel.browsestartpage(),'Beheer/Meta/Zoeken',Off), Autonomous)}" method="post">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q"  title="Type hier uw zoekterm"  placeholder="Ik zoek ..." />
                <input type="hidden" value="0" name="searchconcept" id="c"  />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" value="{locale.getstring('search',default='Zoek')}" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
                </span>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add below css

```
a.logo{
    display:block;
    width:30%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: you can change width in % according to your requirement.